# storing 2D char array created in a function

Tags: arrays, c, char, 2d

im trying to create 2D array in a function and that keep it for later use.
i have this:

```
char **add_to_list(char *str) {
    char list[4][7];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 4) {
        if (i == 1) {
            strcpy(list[i], str);
        }
        else {
            strcpy(list[i], "diff_str");
        }
        i++;
    }
    return list;
}

int main() {
    char **list[4][7];
    char *str = "string";
    **list = add_to_list(str);
}
```

but when add_to_list returns, list isnt what i expected

Comment: When asking debugging questions, always include a [mre]. That should include complete source code that others can compile (and, if the problem is not a compilation or link problem, execute) without any changes or insertions. E.g., it should include `#include <string.h>` if the program uses string functions. It should also include an explanation of why you think there is a problem, notably a copy of the observed output or other behavior and an example of the output or behavior that is desired instead or an explanation of why the observed output is not what is desired.

Comment: After inserting `#include <string.h>`, compiling the code in the question produces warning messages, one because `list` is the wrong type to return for the function and the second because `return list;` returns an address of an automatic object inside the function. The memory reservation for that object is released when the function returns, so the address should not be used after the function returns. Those should be the problems you ask about first; they should be fixed before anything else is done with the program.

Comment: Aside from those, you have not said how the program behavior is not what you expected. You did not say what you expect, nor how you observe any program behavior. The program does not print any output, so how did you see what it does? Did you observe it in a debugger? You need to say that and to show the debugger output (as text, not an image).

Comment: `strcpy(list[i], "diff_str");` attempts to copy nine characters (“diff_str” plus a terminating null character) into an array that is defined to have only seven characters. There is not enough room, and the behavior is not defined.

Comment: `char **list[4][7];` declares `list` to be an array of 4 arrays of 7 pointers to pointers to `char`. That is well beyond what you seem to be trying to do. If you want `main` to provide the memory for the strings, declare `list` to with `char list[4][7];` and pass it to the function. If you want the function to provide the memory, it needs to call `malloc` and return a pointer of the type `char (*)[7]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I simplified it since you are using a static allocated matrix.  I also pointed out the new string added in the else clause is larger than 7. eg. `"diff_str"`.  Its 8 characters plus 1 for the NULL terminating byte.  As a result, I adjusted the size of your static allocation from 7 to 9.  Good luck as you continue to learn C.

```
void add_to_list(char ppList[4][9], char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 4) {
        if (i == 1) {
            strcpy(ppList[i], str);
        }
        else {
            strcpy(ppList[i], "diff_str"); // this string is 9 chars when
                                           // counting NULL terminating byte
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main() {
    // adjusted size of bytes used to hold string
    char list[4][9] = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
    char *str = "string";
    printf("str is %s\n", str);
    printf("list[0] is %s\n", list[0]);
    printf("list[1] is %s\n", list[1]);
    printf("list[2] is %s\n", list[2]);
    printf("list[3] is %s\n", list[3]);
    add_to_list(list, str);
    printf("list[0] is %s\n", list[0]);
    printf("list[1] is %s\n", list[1]);
    printf("list[2] is %s\n", list[2]);
    printf("list[3] is %s\n", list[3]);
}
```

When run it looks like this:

```
str is string
list[0] is one
list[1] is two
list[2] is three
list[3] is four
list[0] is diff_str
list[1] is string
list[2] is diff_str
list[3] is diff_str
```